# FOUND_ROWS() in MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-calc-found-rows

I have a function which needs the number of rows returned by a select. After some googling i found the FOUND_ROWS() function. But i don't think it works:

```
SELECT * FROM tipfirme LIMIT 20;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

because it always returns 1 as the found value.

However, if i run it in one line, it works.

```
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() FROM (SELECT * FROM tipfirme LIMIT 20) as T
```

Am i doing something wrong or is the function broken?

Comment: Your first example should have worked. How many rows were returned by the `SELECT *` query?

Comment: You execute via some connector? it executes a lot of statements hiddenly before/after each call.

Comment: I execute it through phpmyadmin interface. so nothing fancy. i should get a recordcount of around 10, so very small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND_ROWS returns the number of rows the previous request (entire select statement) returned.  It sounds to me like you are wanting just:

```
select count(1) from (select * From tipfirme limit 20) as T
```

`select found_rows();` separately would not always return 1; I suspect you were not testing what you meant to test.  If it immediately follows `select * from tipfirme limit 20;` it would indeed return the number of rows the select returned (after the limit, or before the limit if you specified `sql_calc_found_rows` in the previous select).

`SELECT FOUND_ROWS() FROM (SELECT * FROM tipfirme LIMIT 20) as T` isn't doing what you think; it will return as many rows as the subselect returned, and each will have the number of rows the *previously executed* select returned, not related to the number of rows from the subselect at all.

Comment: It doesn't work with update queries. For those you use `ROW_COUNT()`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks .

Comment: thanks for the "select count(1) from (select * From tipfirme limit 20) as T". it works and i should've thought about it...  to make it more clear: i just ran those to lines of sql. nothing more, nothing less, from the SQL window of phpmyadmin. I'm using mariadb stored on a synology nas

Answer (score 0):

First, launch your query, but add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` before the columns clause:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tipfirme LIMIT 20;
```

and afterwards run

```sql
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

To get how many rows would the query returned without the `LIMIT`

MariaDB docs: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/found_rows/